# Running R script from Java

Tags: java, eclipse, r

I have a R script I need to call from Java and run. I tried this code: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript pathTo/R/myScript.R")`. I run it from windows command it worked fine, but when I run java class with this code in Eclipse, nothing happens. The console doesnt show anything no error no logs. Can someone tell me how to run this script from Java?

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `Process` launched from java has its standard input, standard output and standard error redirected to pipes, which you can access from within java. Unless you read from the standard output and error pipes and transfer the text to the output of the Java application yourself, no output will become visible. Furthermore, if the internal buffer of the pipe gets full, then the child application might even block while waiting for root to write its data. So the process probably will hang and never terminate.

Since Java 7, you can have the child process inherit its I/O channels from your Java application using [`ProcessBuilder.inheritIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29). That saves you all the trouble to read from those streams yourself.